# MySql cumulative total grouped by day on maximum total

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sum, window-functions

I am trying to calculate a cumulative sum of values that can occur more than once on a given day. Therefore i only want to keep the max value for each given day.

currently i have:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m') AS day1,
  SUM(principal) over (order by created_at) AS tot
FROM loan;
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
    {
        "day1" : "21/08",
        "tot" : 200
    },
    {
        "day1" : "21/08",
        "tot" : 1200
    },
    {
        "day1" : "21/08",
        "tot" : 2200
    },
    {
        "day1" : "21/08",
        "tot" : 2500
    },
    {
        "day1" : "25/08",
        "tot" : 4500
    },
    {
        "day1" : "25/08",
        "tot" : 6500
    },
    {
        "day1" : "27/08",
        "tot" : 7000
    },
    {
        "day1" : "27/08",
        "tot" : 7600
    }
]
```

I know i need to group it by the day, but it needs to take the max value for each group of days. any ideas?

When i group by like so:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m') AS day1,
  SUM(principal) over (order by created_at) AS tot
FROM loan
GROUP BY day1;
```

**I Get:**

```
[
    {
        "day1" : "21/08",
        "tot" : 1000
    },
    {
        "day1" : "25/08",
        "tot" : 3000
    },
    {
        "day1" : "27/08",
        "tot" : 3500
    },
    {
        "day1" : "30/08",
        "tot" : 4200
    }
]
```

Which is obviously wrong. Im not sure why it gives that output. But how could i get it to be correct?

Comment: Please show us the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the sums:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d/%m') AS day1,
       SUM(SUM(principal)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(created_at)) AS tot
FROM loan
GROUP BY day1;
```

I am surprised that your version works at all.  It would fail in most databases, because neither `principal` nor `created_at` are aggregation keys.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want:

```
select
    date_format(created_at, '%d/%m') as day1,
    max(sum(principal) over (order by created_at)) as tot
from loan
group by day1
```

Actually, you could also express this with `distinct`, and a slightly different `order by` clause:

```
select distinct
    date_format(created_at, '%d/%m') as day1,
    sum(principal) over (order by date(created_at)) as tot
from loan
```

I am not a big fan of the way you represent dates; if your data spreads over more than one year, the result will become ambiguous (in the second option), or even wrong (in the first query). I would recommend adding the year to the date representation, or simply `date(created_at)`, which basically truncates the time portion.